# Proportional editing functionality

Tags: proportional-editing

No matter what I tried only the immediate area around the center rotated and deformed.

According to everything I could read about proportional editing I am supposed to be able to increase the range of influence by scrolling my mouse wheel or using the Page up or down keys.

The mouse wheel just zoom the scene like always.  And page up or down does nothing at all.  Did they change the functionality in 3.0?
Thanks

Comment: please make a screenshot when you are trying to scroll your mouse....

Comment: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/3dview/controls/proportional_editing.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order for the mouse wheel to work with proportional editing, you need to be doing an action with that option "ON", like <kbd>G</kbd>(Move) <kbd>S</kbd>(scale) or <kbd>R</kbd>(Rotate)

An example is:

In edit mode select a vertex from your mesh

Turn On proportional editing <kbd>O</kbd>

Press <kbd>G</kbd> (move)

And now you can scroll the mouse to make the Proportional editing area Bigger or smaller.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much.  That does the trick.