# How Can I Smoothly Deform / Shape This Mesh?

Tags: modeling

[image]

How can I smoothly deform this curved shape without it looking like the second image?

[image]

Comment: Use proportional editing (Shortcut - O). Scroll the mouse wheel to change the area of affect. It might be a bit laggy with that many verts though.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Proportional editing functionality](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/247296/proportional-editing-functionality)

Comment: BTW. Unless you want to sculpt/displace fine details into this mesh, the polygon density looks way too high.. depending on what you want to achieve, if you were using a Subdivision Surface modifier on a leaner mesh, you may only have to move one or two vertices on the original.