# How to model this wavy container jar?

Tags: modeling, modifiers

I'm pretty new to Blender modelling. I just have to make something like the Containter Jar. What trick or modifier can be used to get the wavy effect?

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Proportional editing functionality](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/247296/proportional-editing-functionality)

Comment: Alternatively, check out the [Lattice](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/animation/lattice.html) modifier.

Comment: or the wave modifier

Comment: or geometry nodes

Answer (score 3):

Here my first solution with a wave modifier:

[image]

[image]

I started with a default cylinder, sized it on z, then deleted the bottom and top face, filled them again with grid fill, then used the 2 modifiers.

[image]

[image]

---

Geometry nodes:

[image]

modifier stack:

[image]

[image]

---

proportional editing:

Cylinder modeled as described in first solution, then select middle vertices and just move it:

[image]

Comment: Ha, wonderful, three viable solutions at once! Beautiful!